# removing ghost databases

Tags: postgresql

For some up-to-now undefined reason, a number of ghost databases have been created:

```
 mrkt_test-0         | deploy_root | UTF8     | C       | C     |
 mrkt_test-1         | deploy_root | UTF8     | C       | C     |
 mrkt_test-2         | deploy_root | UTF8     | C       | C     |
 mrkt_test-3         | deploy_root | UTF8     | C       | C     |
 mrkt_test-4         | deploy_root | UTF8     | C       | C     |
 mrkt_test-5         | deploy_root | UTF8     | C       | C     |
 mrkt_test-6         | deploy_root | UTF8     | C       | C     |
 mrkt_test-7         | deploy_root | UTF8     | C       | C     |
```

However, attempting to drop any table with a dash leads to:

```
 DROP DATABASE  mrkt_test-0;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: DROP DATABASE  mrkt_test-0;
```

`mrkt_test` of its own was dropped, but the ghosts are still lying around.
It appears they may be at the origin of some connection issues with the test suite for the connecting application.
How do they get cleaned up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

```
DROP DATABASE "mrkt_test-0";
```